How to using the power bi query with dynamic IP
I am using the power BI desktop to do some query from my Azure SQL, But since azure SQL database has turned on the network, and the IP of my personal PC has not been added to the whitelist of azure SQL database's network firewall, I cannot successfully connect to Azure SQL database:

However my PC's IP is dynamic and adding my IP to Azure sql database every time is not possible. Is there a way to solve this problem, using FQDN?


My PC's IP is dynamic, and adding my IP to Azure SQL Database every time is not possible. Is there a way to solve this problem?

To solve the problem, you can create a firewall rule with a start IP of 0.0.0.0 and an end IP of 255.255.255.255 in the networking tab of Azure SQL Server, as shown below:

Then, you will be able to connect Azure SQL Database to Power BI without adding IP addresses, as shown below:

Alternatively, you can use a Private Endpoint. For more information, you can refer to this SO answer.
